# STL map usage for 16 GB of data on a 64 bit machine

Tags: c++

This may sound interesting(or may weired), I just wanted to upload a very large database into memory(this can go from 12GB to 16 GB).The file will get uploaded every day in memory and will subsequently will be used for that whole day(and so on).
  Is it alright if I use STL map for this use case?Does STL map works fine with that kind of data size on 64bit machine(if anyone have any experience working on this kind of problem).Also the no. of queries to that STL map will be around 1000 per second.
Let me know if anyone have any experience working on this kind of problem or I should go for some other data structure(any third party tool which can reliably do so) ?

My main issue is that I want to save my I/O time in realtime.But I also have mysql as my database where I need to persist this data.Is it Ok If I use sqlite as "in memory" DB and then I save that data in mysql(on disk) ?I think mysql also provides "MySQL Cluster" for something similar but I don't know how useful it is practically.

Comment: Rearranging a map with around 12 GB of data on an insert is too much of waste of resources.

Comment: More interesting is: Number of elements. What actions you will do on the map, and in what volume/ratio will each action will be done.

Comment: My god. An `stl::map` with 12GB worth of elements? The access times would be insane.

Comment: @ DumbCoder: Are you trying to suggest that the whole tree is re-balanced after each insert? Remember the standard guarantees a insert complexity into a map of O(ln(n))

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: Access complexity is: O(ln(n)). Assuming each element is 4 bytes and a simple binary tree representation thats less than 16 comparisons to find an element (not exactly heavy lifting for a computer). The question really is how much space are you willing to give up for extra speed.

Comment: @Martin: "Assuming each element is 4 bytes" is a big assumption. ;)

Comment: @jonathan his point is that that's the worst-case. If each element is small, then you have a larger tree and longer insert, access, and delete times. If each element is instead something like 100Mb, then his point is all the more well-founded.

Comment: I know, I know. I still don't think an `stl::map` ought to have 12GB worth of elements. I think that in and of itself is indicative of deeper problems.

Comment: @Jonathan I agree; that was the entire point of my answer.

Comment: @San: I think my point may be that I need coffee. >.>

Comment: @Jonathan: Yes you are correct, we are probably getting towards the extreme use of a map here (depending on data element size this could be feasible (large data element size) or totally imposable (small data element size)).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is a good idea. To efficiently manage such a big quantity of data you'll need many optimizations. `std::map` won't probably be optimized for your scenario, plus I'm afraid the algorithms you could write to handle it won't be as efficient as possible.

I'd suggest you to use a database for your purpose. If your bottleneck is disk I/O then configure your database to cache more information (even 16GB, if you've got enough memory) on ram.

Comment: @Martin York: network delay? I was thinking about setting up a DB on the machine where OP's application runs.

Comment: @Martin York, an in-memory database would solve the round trip problem and may be as quick as a std::map (or faster if it's really good).

Comment: @Martin York: I wasn't referring to big DBMS with servers; an embedded DB like SQLite could be fine and it shouldn't have the overhead of server-based DBs. Anyway a server-based DB could still be a good idea if the OP needs to work with billions of small items; IPC for small messages isn't that expensive, and I'm pretty sure that a good DB could have many optimization (for examples in exploiting cache) that I think would help a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I personally would use an `unordered_map`, which offers O(1) insertion, lookup, etc. However, the real question is the number of items in it, not the actual size of them.

Comment: I think you miss the problems entirely. For this use case and data sets of this size (log 2 of 1 billion is close to 30), O(log(n)) is practically O(1), as Martin York points out in a comment. You lose a lot of really good, tested, and optimized code by implementing this yourself with an std container.

Comment: I'm not really sure that you're producing a competitive argument here. Only O(30) vs O(1)? More importantly, there are perfectly high quality unordered containers in the Standard libraries of any TR1 or C++0x compiler and there's one in Boost too.

Comment: O(30) == O(1), and there may be very good run-time reasons to choose a )(log(n)) alg over a O(1) alg.. but that isn't my point at all and is something that _you_ introduced, not I. You can see my answer for the things that I think you are overlooking.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you look into in-process DBs e.g. www.sqlite.org for that purpose.

Comment: My main issue is that I want to save my I/O time in realtime.But I also have mysql as my database where I need to persist this data.Is it Ok If I use sqlite as "in memory" DB and then I save that data in mysql(on disk) ?I think mysql also provides "MySQL Cluster" for something similar but I don't know how useful it is practically.

Answer (score -1):

There are good reasons why I wouldn't even think of doing this, any of which may or may not apply to you:

1. Concurrent access goes from a proven RDBMS to something hacked on top of std::map
2. I don't have 16 GB of RAM.
3. Loading it from disk the first time will take FOREVER.
4. Maintaining 2 full copies of data is just ASKING for data integrity issues.
5. etc.

I just think this is a bad idea.